# Modal Property 'show' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I use the `Modal` component exactly as shown in the `react-bootstrap` docs but I get the error `Property 'show' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & [...]'`

```
<Modal show={props.showModal} onHide={props.handleCloseModal}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Seleccionaste la opcion:</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
[...]
```

Comment: React-bootstrap is actually written in typescript so this doesn't make sense. Double check your versions

Comment: I know it doesn't make any sense. I double checked the versions multiple times. I even dived into the source code from my node_modules and react-bootstrap github. In the end I installed @types/react-bootstrap and that solved it

Answer (score 1):

After digging in `node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Modal.d.ts` I found that effectively `show` doesn't exist on the type definitions for `react-bootstrap@^1.3.0` (weird because is the latest version according to the official website and even the docs tell you to use that prop).

So my solution was to install `@types/react-bootstrap` where the `show` props was definitely included. That solved my problem!